How to properly resize single row/column in flexbox
Here is what I have:

And here is what I need:

is there a way to set second item height to max window height without setting "height" property?
My code in React.js
return (
        <div className="App" style={{ padding: "10px", border: "1px solid red", display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <div style={{padding: "10px", border: "1px solid green", width: "100%"}}> row 1</div>
            <div style={{padding: "10px", border: "1px solid blue", width: "100%"}}> row 2</div>
        </div>
    );


Nope, you have to set a height somewhere so that the element can be 100% of it.

Also your "rows" are in fact columns....and will have equal height if their parent is display:flex.

You wish to set Height without setting Height?

I wish to set it's height auto to window height

Nope, that still setting a height....

OK. how do I redesign it then? By setting flex-direction: "column" ?

setting container height: 100vh kinda work... but not really good

Even if you set the container height to 100vh, you still need to set the height of the child to 100%.... and again, the two children will have the same height unless you set align-items: start; on the parent. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/poBGdGW
